# how to get key value from json result in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

**how can I get specify email and its value only, from JSON array result which should be like=>only( email: abc@gmail.com)**

here is my code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("Scream_It");
  var query = { bid_location : 'abbottabad' };
  dbo.collection("bid_placement").find(query).sort({bid_amount:-1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
       var string = JSON.stringify(result);
       console.log(string);
        var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
       // console.log(objectValue);
       console.log(objectValue.email);
```

this is the result which i am getting in console

```
[ { _id: 5a9f8849fc49ca1ff4aee3dc,
    email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    bid_amount: '200',
    bid_time: '22:22:22:22',
    bid_location: 'abbottabad',
    bid_status: 'false' } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple JavaScript:

```js
var res = [ 
   { _id: '5a9f8849fc49ca1ff4aee3dc',
    email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    bid_amount: '200',
    bid_time: '22:22:22:22',
    bid_location: 'abbottabad',
    bid_status: 'false' },
   { _id: '5a9f8849fc49ca1ff4aee3dd',
    email: 'abcd@gmail.com',
    bid_amount: '200',
    bid_time: '22:22:22:22',
    bid_location: 'abbottabad',
    bid_status: 'false' },
   { _id: '5a9f8849fc49ca1ff4aee3de',
    email: 'abcde@gmail.com',
    bid_amount: '200',
    bid_time: '22:22:22:22',
    bid_location: 'abbottabad',
    bid_status: 'false' }
];

var finalRes = res.map(({email}) => ({email}));
console.log(finalRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` or `map` on your array:

Using reduce

```
reducedResults = result.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
   accumulator.push({ email: current.email });
   return accumulator;
}, [])
```

Using map

```
mappedResults = result.map((user) => {
   return { email: user.email };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `select` method from [mongoose api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html). Basically, you can control with it what will result object contains of its properties. So, your code could look like this:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("Scream_It");
  var query = { bid_location : 'abbottabad' };
  dbo.collection("bid_placement").find(query).select({email: 1, _id: 0}).sort({bid_amount:-1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
       var string = JSON.stringify(result);
       console.log(string);
        var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
       // console.log(objectValue);
       console.log(objectValue.email);
```

You should get something like this:

```
[ { email: 'abc@gmail.com'} ]
```

If you need `_id`, use this in select `{email: 1, _id: 1}`